# SQL Server 2012 SSIS :environment properties sensitive check box is not showing

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

New to SSIS and when following through coursework I find that the sensitive check box is missing when I clicking on the Variables tab of the Environment Properties.

I first suspected that this was a display problem so changed the display down to 1024x768 but still nothing.  The is just a long blank space.

It's driving me mad.  If anyone has seen this before and can let me know what it is I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Your screen looks different to mine. Buttons and fonts larger - it's a different font too. Also, on the permissions tab do you have Read, Modify and Manage Permissions set? 

You may want to edit your question so that the link is formatted correctly in your question.

Comment: I can't add any more screenshots but on the permissions tab I have dbo as read modify and manage permissions.  I can't edit any of these or add anyone else to this list.  I am logged on with the Server Administrator account which also has sysadmin permissions on the sql server.

Comment: Try resetting your gui to the default fonts, sizes etc. Also - anything in the logs?

Comment: I am now in the middle of a full test to see what this issue is.  I am unable to enter or amend any SSIS environments.  I am building a test Domain and member server in the lab, will install sql and then test environments.  I will then connect different monitors on to it to test if this issue still occurs after all that.  This is taking me a liitle tim fitting it in but I will update you with an answer on how I get on once I

Comment: Wow long winded but built test server, reinstalled sql and still get the same issue.

Comment: environment Production1 READ
environment Production1 MODIFY
environment Production1 MANAGE_PERMISSIONS  Absolutely baffled by this

Comment: Add another screenshot with default fonts and sizes pls

Answer (score 0):

It was a hardware issue on the server so installing to different hardware resolved.  If the hosting server doesn't have a large graphics handling capability the display misses things out, even when rdping to it.  Thanks for the help.